# Error de compilación en un formulario C# y SQL server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy tratando de extraer datos de una base de datos local `RIDO`que contiene una tabla (`ESTUDIANTES`). Estoy siguiendo un manual que encontré en internet, pero una vez que asocio el `DataGridView` con la conexión establecida con la base de datos (`RidoDataSet`). Simplemente me sale error de compilación, tal como lo ven en la imagen adjunta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `DataGridView` si hace referencia de alguna manera (Por eso salen los campos de la tabla en ella) Sin ningún problema, pero no entiendo por que tengo errores de compilación.

Ya que me están pidiendo el código les envío el código donde ocurre el error:

```
namespace Form1
{
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Variable del diseñador requerida.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Limpiar los recursos que se estén utilizando.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true si los recursos administrados se deben eliminar; false en caso contrario, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Código generado por el Diseñador de Windows Forms

    /// <summary>
    /// Método necesario para admitir el Diseñador. No se puede modificar
    /// el contenido del método con el editor de código.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.rIDODataSet = new Form1.RIDODataSet();//RIDODataSet()
        this.eSTUDIANTESBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
        this.eSTUDIANTESTableAdapter = new Form1.RIDODataSetTableAdapters.ESTUDIANTESTableAdapter();//RIDODataSetTableAdapters
        this.mATRICULADataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.nOMBREDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.aPELLIDODataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.tELEFONODataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.rIDODataSet)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eSTUDIANTESBindingSource)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.mATRICULADataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.nOMBREDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.aPELLIDODataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.tELEFONODataGridViewTextBoxColumn});
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.eSTUDIANTESBindingSource;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 100);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(447, 150);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // rIDODataSet
        // 
        this.rIDODataSet.DataSetName = "RIDODataSet";
        this.rIDODataSet.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
        // 
        // eSTUDIANTESBindingSource
        // 
        this.eSTUDIANTESBindingSource.DataMember = "ESTUDIANTES";
        this.eSTUDIANTESBindingSource.DataSource = this.rIDODataSet;
        // 
        // eSTUDIANTESTableAdapter
        // 
        this.eSTUDIANTESTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
        // 
        // mATRICULADataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.mATRICULADataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "MATRICULA";
        this.mATRICULADataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "MATRICULA";
        this.mATRICULADataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "mATRICULADataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        // 
        // nOMBREDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.nOMBREDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "NOMBRE";
        this.nOMBREDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "NOMBRE";
        this.nOMBREDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "nOMBREDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        // 
        // aPELLIDODataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.aPELLIDODataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "APELLIDO";
        this.aPELLIDODataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "APELLIDO";
        this.aPELLIDODataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "aPELLIDODataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        // 
        // tELEFONODataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.tELEFONODataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "TELEFONO";
        this.tELEFONODataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "TELEFONO";
        this.tELEFONODataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "tELEFONODataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(538, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.rIDODataSet)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eSTUDIANTESBindingSource)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private RIDODataSet rIDODataSet;
    private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource eSTUDIANTESBindingSource;
    private RIDODataSetTableAdapters.ESTUDIANTESTableAdapter eSTUDIANTESTableAdapter;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn mATRICULADataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn nOMBREDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn aPELLIDODataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tELEFONODataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
}
```

}

También les adjunto las imágenes de los errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el detalle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Aquí les dejo el link del manual que estuve siguiendo:

https://profesorezequielruizgarcia.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/youblisher-com-513610-bases_de_datos_sql_server_con_c_.pdf

Comment: Recuerda que siempre que creas un dataset dentro de un proyecto tienes que compilarlo, para luego poder seleccionar el datasource como un objeto y seleccionas el RIDODDataset, y ya seleccionas el tableadapter segun la tabla que tengas en la DB. Aparte que si dentro del DataSet no has puesto las tablas es probable que también te de problemas.

Comment: Recién estoy comenzando en este lenguaje y entorno de desarrollo, por eso es que estaba con un manual, pero tuve este error, lamento no haberte entendido, tal vez si me explicaras el procedimiento sería mejor. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

A simple vista, parece ser que el nombre no esta respetando minúsculas y mayúsculas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa ese detalle :-)  Saludos

Dale doble clic al error y te va mandar a al línea de código, allí cambia el nombre a como lo declaraste al parecer es `rIDODataSet` y  no `RIDODataSet`,  podrías anexar código también.

En tu línea:

```
this.eSTUDIANTESTableAdapter = new Form1.RIDODataSetTableAdapters.ESTUDIANTESTableAdapter();//RIDODataSetTableAdapters
```

Creo que debes cambiar `Form1` por `this`.

Mira el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Momento... ya estoy viendo el detalle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En estas lineas... cuando pongas `= new` presiona <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Barra espacio</kbd>, visual te va decir como debes inicializarlos.. en el caso del `dataset` debe ser `new Dataset();`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen no puedes inicializarlos como un OBJETO, si no como un TIPO, aparte de que `Form1.RIDODataset` no existe... debe ser del tipo de dato que se están declarando.... `DataSet` y `DataAdapter`... etc.

Comment: Gracias por responder Cristina, acabo de editar la pregunta.

Comment: Ok, mira cuando pones `Form1.` <-- Visual te deberia sugerir las opciones disponibles... si pones el `.` y le das <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>barra de espacio</kbd>, o <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>barra de espacio</kbd>, te aparecerá una lista con las sugerencias allí debería estar el nombre correcto del objeto que quieres utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un breve tutorial, espero te sirva para utilizarlo de manera automatizada.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente te preguntara que tabla quiere utilizar para el tableadapter.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez seleccionado el tableadapter, te rellenara automáticamente los statements de: update, delete, select, delete. 
Recuerda que tienes que poner las tablas en el dataset. (Con solo arrastrarlas de tu server explorer)